# How to use https to securely send passwords from client to server on localhost

Tags: php, javascript, html, http, https

I looked for hours and I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm currently testing a website on my laptop(local host).
My site has a server side(php) and a client side.

I'm looking for away to send password using HTTPS, without specifying the absolute path.
(My php and html are in the same directory)

My code looks like that:

```
      <!-- Submit data to server-side -->
      <form name="input" action="databasebuilder.php" method="post">
          <ul>
             <li>User name: <input type="text" name="user"> </li>
             <li>Password: <input type="text" name="password"> </li>
             <li>First name: <input type="text" name="name"> </li>
             <li>Last name: <input type="text" name="last"> </li>
             <li>Email: <input type="text" name="email"> </li>
         </ul>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

Comment: If the form isn't already on HTTPS, there is no way to do that.

Comment: You want to tell me that each time I sign up to a site it is opening a new html page in https, for credentials?

Comment: You can use Ajax, too. But you'll probably have to give it an absolute path. Why don't you want that?

Comment: @Alon well, no - but when they switch from http to https, those other sites don't have a problem specifying an absolute path. Why do you?

Comment: I've never uploaded a website to the internet before, I don't know yet if I'd gave to use absolute path or not so I'd like to keep it as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either choose an absolute path or make sure that the page will be loaded using `HTTPS`. If the user types

```
http://localhost/...
```

in browser, your web application should redirect to:

```
https://localhost
```

You can ensure this for example using PHP or apache's `mod_rewrite`

---

You can create the absolute path dynamically using PHP. Have a look at this example:

```
$path  = 'https://';
$path .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
$path .= 'path/to/your/app/action.php';
echo '<form action="' . $path . '"....';
```

Comment: I don't understand. I'm using  action="databasebuilder.php". I don't want client to load page in https I want only the action to be performed in https

Comment: Loading the page over http and send the form with https using a relative path is not possible. Either use an absolute path or load the page using https

Comment: But using an absolute path will force me to change the code once it is uploaded to the real server? no

Comment: yes. since you have `location.host` it is possible. Maybe this helps you further: Or check this: stackoverflow.com/questions/4140324/parse-url-with-javascript

Comment: Well correct me if I'm wrong but to do it in JS will be a mistake since I need the location of the server and the Javascript will run on client side once I'd upload the files to the server. So I suppose the PHP is the only option here

Comment: `location.host` will contain the name of the *server* where the page has been loaded from